# how to inspect nodejs express middleware options and parameters

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I would like to inspect some middleware options I am setting for express later in the code. For instance I am setting limits in json bodyParser as:

```
expressServer.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit:1000000
}))
```

Then later in the code I would like to retrieve that value from the express instance for further needs.

To use this "limit" as a global variable would not be a desired solution.

Comment: I don't think there's any reasonable way of doing this (the unreasonable way would be to delve into the app instance, find the `body-parser` middleware instance, and hope that `limit` is somehow an accessible property). You're going to have to store it _somewhere_ (for instance, using [`app.set()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set)).

Answer (score 0):

You can store options in database or in a simple file:

```
{
    "bodyParserLimit": 10000
}
```

And then access it by reading file

```
// implement this function
readOptionsFromFile(function() {
    expressServer.use(bodyParser.json({
       limit: options.bodyParserLimit
    }))
})
```

So you can call `readOptionsFromFile(callback)` from wherever you want.

Comment: Then I rather store it into a local variable, but I was hoping to easily access the middleware as intuitively as:  expressServer. middleware.body-parser.json.options.limit

Comment: As far as I know express is not providing that api.